# Проверить json на возможность деcериализации symfony serializer

Tags: php, json, symfony

Есть api ресурс, который может возвратить как ошибку:

```php
class ResponseWrongDto {
    /**
      * @var errors[]
      */
    private $errors = [];

    /**
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getErrors(): array
    {
        return $this->errors;
    }

    /**
     * @param string[] $errors
     */
    public function setErrors(array $errors): void
    {
        $this->errors $errors;
    }
}
```

так и полезные данные

```php
class ResponseDto
{
    /** @var string */
    private $id;

    /** @var string */
    private $value;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getId(): string
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $id
     */
    public function setId(string $agentId): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getValue(): string
    {
        return $this->value;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $value
     */
    public function setValue(string $value): void
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }
}
```

Сериалайзером пытаюсь проверить возможна ли денормализация ответа, например на ошибку:

```php
$isError = $serializer->supportsDenormalization($jsonStr, ResponseWrongDto::class, 'json');
```

но каким бы не был $jsonStr (хоть {"aa":11}) всегда получаю  true.
Подскажите, что делаю не так?

Comment: По [документации](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) у вас должен быть зарегистрирован денормализатор, наследующий от [DenormalizerInterface](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.1/src/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Normalizer/DenormalizerInterface.php), в котором вы должны и делать соответствующую проверку. Приведите код для создания $serializer, иначе нам останется только гадать.

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov Сериалайзер использую совместно с симфони, т.е. через инъекцию SerializerInterface, соответственно, нормолайзер дефолтный(мега ObjectNormalaizer)

Comment: Обычно по http кодам ответа разделяется куда кинуть. Код 200 $serializer, иначе исключение и его serializer что бы понять что за ошибка.

Comment: @hardworm по кодам это хорошо, но в данном случае предоставляемый  api может иметь до 4-х варианов ответов на один урл при статусе 200

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите хотя бы на одну реализацию метода `supportsDenormalization`, в основном, он проверяет не структуру данных, а их тип на соответствие, в таком случае, да, вы всегда получаете положительное значение.

Вы можете сделать что-то подобное:
// `$data` - ваши данные + какое-то несуществующее поле для `ResponseWrongDto`, например, вам дополнительно отдали `city`.

```
try { 
    // this will throw a Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\ExtraAttributesException
    // because "city" is not an attribute of the ResponseWrongDto class
    $errorDTO = $serializer->deserialize($data, ResponseWrongDto::class, 'json', [
         AbstractNormalizer::ALLOW_EXTRA_ATTRIBUTES => false,
    ]);
} catch (ExtraAttributesException $eErr) {
    try {
        $responseDTO = $serializer->deserialize($data, ResponseDto::class, 'json', [
            AbstractNormalizer::ALLOW_EXTRA_ATTRIBUTES => false,
        ]);
    } catch (ExtraAttributesException $eBadReq) {
        // Здесь, определите ваше поведение, если данные не подошли 
        // для ResponseWrongDto и ResponseDto соответственно. 
        //Такое может быть и сервер должен обработать такой кейс. 
        // Можно выкинуть BadREquestHttpException - например статус 
        // с кодом 422 (unprocessable entity), чтобы дать понять клиенту,
        // что мы не можем работать с этими данными. 
    }
}

// Далее, ваша логика с ResponseWrongDto или же ResponseDto, 
// в зависимости от того, что получили.
```